# how to disable the error:idea javadoc error: identifier expected

Tags: intellij-idea

our project is editting in eclipse so far. but i try to import our project into idea, but meet many errors, it cause by one punctuation in javadoc, like picture 1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgYJn.png),

and i have decreased the hightlevel, but it shows error, either.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqon8.png)

pls give me some advice about it..  thank you ...

Comment: Please remove dot after "Exception" or add space before the dot.